# Have/having choice simple question

Tags: questions

Which sentence is correct (or maybe both of them wrong or right)? What's difference between them?

"What problem do you have with this?";
"What problem are you having with this?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't exactly explain why, but:

"What problem do you have with this?" relates to something abstract, like a political issue. "What problem do you have with us getting married?"

"What problem are you having with this?" relates to an immediate, physical problem. "What problem are you having with this clutch?"

I think the second sense could also apply to the "do you have" form, but not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

The second one is wrong, as you are only asking for one problem, not multiple ones.  The first one "What problem do you have with this," can also be stated, "What *is* the (singular) problem?"  For the second one, to use *are*, you would need to allow for multiple problems - so, "What problems are you having with this?"

As for have vs having, both would be correct if "problems" were plural.  "What problems do you have (at this moment in time)?"  or "What problems are you having (over the a period of time)?"

Comment: This answer is wrong. Both of these sentences are correct. "Are" goes with "you", not "problem", so problem doesn't have to be plural. The meanings of these two sentences are pretty much the same. I don't have a good explanation of the difference between them at the moment.